# Using Regex match for sentences that do not contain a specific word

Tags: regex

Trying to develop a regular expression to extract sentences that don't contain specific words. To keep it simple, IHere is a simple example:

**Input**:
Sagittal scout images cervicothoracic  : Mild-to-moderate multilevel spondylosis. Fracture present.

**Desired Output**:
Fracture present.

Attempt #1

**Regex**:
`[^.]*(?!cervi(c|x))[^.]*\.`

**Actual Output**:
Sagittal scout images cervicothoracic  : Mild-to-moderate multilevel spondylosis. Fracture present.

Attempt #2:

**Regex**:
`[^.]*[^(cervi(c|x))][^.]*\.`

**Actual Output**:
Sagittal scout images cervicothoracic  : Mild-to-moderate multilevel spondylosis. Fracture present.

Can verify these results in https://regexr.com/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use

```
(?<![^.])\s*((?:(?!cervi[cx])[^.])*\.)
```

See [proof](https://regex101.com/r/IFSglv/1)

**Explanation**

```
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  (?<!                     look behind to see if there is not:
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    [^.]                     any character except: '.'
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  )                        end of look-behind
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  \s*                      whitespace (\n, \r, \t, \f, and " ") (0 or
                           more times (matching the most amount
                           possible))
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  (                        group and capture to \1:
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    (?:                      group, but do not capture (0 or more
                             times (matching the most amount
                             possible)):
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
      (?!                      look ahead to see if there is not:
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
        cervi                    'cervi'
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
        [cx]                     any character of: 'c', 'x'
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
      )                        end of look-ahead
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
      [^.]                     any character except: '.'
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    )*                       end of grouping
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    \.                       '.'
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  )                        end of \1
```

Comment: this does work. but interesting, i'm new to using `?:` with `?!`, logically if you already have the group you don't want to capture (i.e. `(?:)`), why is a lookahead still needed? I experimented with your expression `(?<![^.])\s*(?:cervi[cx][^.]*\.)` and no longer get any matches. Wouldn't regex check the next character after the whitespace to make sure it's not in this group?

Comment: @chethanjjj "Does not capture" does not mean "does not consume". Lookarounds are meant to check pattern presence/absence while the regex index stays where it was before trying the lookaround pattern. Your `(?:cervi[cx][^.]*\.)` is the same as `cervi[cx][^.]*\.`, just matches `cervi`, then `c` or `x`, then any char but a dot zero or more times and then a `.`.

Comment: @chethanjjj Just as Wiktor says. Lookahead is needed as the `[^.]` must be restricted in what it matches, and `(?:(?!cervi[cx])[^.])*`  matches any character other than a period, which is not the first character of `cervix` or `cervic`.